# Sending mail via PHP: How to send mail if attachment is empty?

Tags: php, forms, validation, wordpress

Thanks to a [wonderful tutorial by Agbonghama Collins](http://www.sitepoint.com/client-side-form-validation-html5/), I've begun working on a WP plugin for my personal use, one that outputs a simple contact form with file attachments.

As for now, there are two file attachment fields, but they shouldn't be mandatory. However if either is left empty, the form outputs the following error:

> WARNING: FILE_GET_CONTENTS() [FUNCTION.FILE-GET-CONTENTS]: FILENAME CANNOT BE EMPTY IN ~/SP-FORM-EXAMPLE.PHP ON LINE 55

The email ultimately **does** send, but arrives with two attachments anyway, either one or both of which is empty, depending on what was uploaded to the form. The following image depicts what it looks like if only one attachment was included:

[image: screenshot of "two attachments", when there should only be one]

For the file input fields, I'm calling the variable this way...

```
    if ( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {

            ...

            $first_attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['cf-attachment']['tmp_name'])));
            $first_filename = $_FILES['cf-extra_attachment']['name'];
            $second_attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['cf-attachment']['tmp_name'])));
            $second_filename = $_FILES['cf-extra_attachment']['name'];

            ...
```

... and transmitting the mail as a MIME stream. So, my question is this: **is there any way to allow these variables to be empty when the email is processed and sent, such that the appropriate number of attachments would be included in the sent the email and no error would be returned?** Code examples would be helpful :)

And for clearer reference, here's the entire plugin file. It's very light and uses no helper scripts. Thank you all in advance!!

```
    <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Contact Form Plugin
Plugin URI: http://dbudell.com
Description: Modification to the "Simple non-bloated WordPress Contact Form" by Agbonghama Collins (http://w3guy.com); now allows for file attachments.
Version: 1.0
Author: Daniel Bogre Udell (@dbudell)
Author URI: http://dbudell.com
*/

function html_form_code() {
    echo '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="' . esc_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) . '" method="post">';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Your Name (required) <br/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="cf-name" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-name"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-name"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Your Email (required) <br/>';
    echo '<input type="email" name="cf-email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-email"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-email"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Subject (required) <br/>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="cf-subject" pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" value="' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-subject"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-subject"] ) : '' ) . '" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'File Attachment (required)';
    echo '<input type="file" name="cf-attachment" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Second File Attachment (required)';
    echo '<input type="file" name="cf-extra_attachment" size="40" />';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p>';
    echo 'Your Message (required) <br/>';
    echo '<textarea rows="10" cols="35" name="cf-message">' . ( isset( $_POST["cf-message"] ) ? esc_attr( $_POST["cf-message"] ) : '' ) . '</textarea>';
    echo '</p>';
    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="cf-submitted" value="Send"></p>';
    echo '</form>';
}

function deliver_mail() {

    // if the submit button is clicked, send the email
    if ( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {

        // collect form values
        $name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['cf-name'] );
        $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST['cf-email'] );
        $subject = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['cf-subject'] );
        $message = esc_textarea( $_POST['cf-message'] );
        $first_attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['cf-attachment']['tmp_name'])));
        $first_filename = $_FILES['cf-attachment']['name'];
        $second_attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['cf-extra_attachment']['tmp_name'])));
        $second_filename = $_FILES['cf-extra_attachment']['name'];

        $boundary =md5(date('r', time())); 

        $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );

        $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "\r\nMIME-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"_1_$boundary\"";

        $message="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_2_$boundary\"

--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"_3_$boundary\"

--_3_$boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

$message

--_3_$boundary--
--_2_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$first_filename\" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

$first_attachment
--_2_$boundary--

--_1_$boundary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"$second_filename\" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 
Content-Disposition: attachment 

$second_attachment
--_1_$boundary--";

        // If email has been processed for sending, display a success message
        if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) ) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<p>Thanks for contacting me, expect a response soon.</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
        }
    }
}

function cf_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    deliver_mail();
    html_form_code();

    return ob_get_clean();
}

add_shortcode( 'test_contact_form', 'cf_shortcode' );

?>
```

Comment: if you are on WordPress, you can use `wp_mail` to send e-mail with or without attachement

Comment: I'm actually using wp_mail to send the email (it's towards the bottom of the plugin code), but unfortunately the error is still returned..

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the extra attachment is set and skip the part if not:

```
if(isset($_FILES['cf-extra_attachment']['tmp_name'])) {
    $second_attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['cf-extra_attachment']['tmp_name'])));
    $second_filename = $_FILES['cf-extra_attachment']['name'];
}
```

Comment: thanks! i tried this but unfortunately the error is still returned. could it be that the MIME stream is checking for the variable and finding it empty? if so, how might i include an if () statement in the MIME stream for both attachment boundaries?

Comment: You need to look for `cf-extra-attachement` in code and do the same. Also I noticed that there's `$second_attachment` variable and `$second_filename` that are related. You need to make them conditional too as they will also emit warning

Answer (score 0):

to send attachements with wp_mail, try this

```
function deliver_mail() {

    // if the submit button is clicked, send the email
    if ( isset( $_POST['cf-submitted'] ) ) {

        // collect form values
        $name = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['cf-name'] );
        $email   = sanitize_email( $_POST['cf-email'] );
        $subject = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['cf-subject'] );
        $message = esc_textarea( $_POST['cf-message'] );


        $attachements = array();

        if (isset($_FILES['cf-attachment']['tmp_name'])) {
            $attachements[] = $_FILES['cf-attachment']['tmp_name'];
        }

        if (isset($_FILES['cf-extra_attachment']['tmp_name'])) {
            $attachements[] = $_FILES['cf-extra_attachment']['tmp_name'];
        }


        $to = get_option( 'admin_email' );

        $headers = "From: $name <$email>" . "\r\n";

        // If email has been processed for sending, display a success message
        if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachements ) ) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<p>Thanks for contacting me, expect a response soon.</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
        }
    }
}
```

or another version with setting of the names of the attachements :

```
        add_action("phpmailer_init", function ($phpmailer) {

            if (isset($_FILES['cf-attachment']['tmp_name'])) {
                $phpmailer->addAttachment(
                    $_FILES['cf-attachment']['tmp_name']
                    , $_FILES['cf-attachment']['name']
                );
            }

            if (isset($_FILES['cf-extra_attachment']['tmp_name'])) {
                $phpmailer->addAttachment(
                    $_FILES['cf-extra_attachment']['tmp_name']
                    , $_FILES['cf-extra_attachment']['name']
                );
            }

        }, 10, 1);


        // If email has been processed for sending, display a success message
        if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers) ) {
            echo '<div>';
            echo '<p>Thanks for contacting me, expect a response soon.</p>';
            echo '</div>';
        } else {
            echo 'An unexpected error occurred';
        }
```